# Clustering 2 lists

Tags: python, clustering

I have a dataset that contains 2 columns based on experimental data. Both columns contain lists of the same length. One column equals to the argument, where the list is the same for every sample. The corresponding values of the list in the target column differ from each other, as they obviously belong to different samples.

I was wondering what I can do to cluster my dataset?

What I did so far, I removed the argument column and splitted the target column so that each list item leads to a new column, so that I have as many new columns as the lenght of the list was. On that I did a dimensionality reduction with clustering afterwards. But this did not lead to good results.

Does anyone have another idea what to do, or a suitable approach?

Comment: You say you tried clustering after dimensionality reduction. What clustering techniques have you tried here? When you say the clustering you tried did not lead to good results, how did you determine that? What would you consider to be a "good result"?

Comment: I did PCA and tSNE for dim reduction. In the PCA I could see in the variance of the PCs already that PC1 only contributed to about 5 % of the information. Then, I plotted the first two PCs as well as the first two obtained features from tSNE and could not see any nice clusters. The variance of the PCA could already show the tendency.